# Translating EMS quotes

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation

I need some assistance. I'm attempting to translate some EMS quotes. Some come from local sources (like bracelets, tshirts, and patches.) Google translate and crowdsourcing has, as of yet, been unreliable, and my latin was many winters ago.

The English followed by the closest I can get in Latin:

From these hands comes healing :
Ex his manibus salus

That by which all others are measured :
Id quo mensurantur omnes alii ordines

So that others may live :
Ut alii sit vivere
(Recommended change to "ut alii vivant")

No one is coming. It's up to us. :
Nemo venit, nobis est omines

Comment: I novice in Latin, but I would consider not using "ex" in "from these hands" , i would use simply manibus (as ablative of means/way) : healing comes using these hands. I think "ex" imply something more of location.